# Nonexistence of a cyclic vector for a representation on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, harmonic-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $S$ be the bilateral shift on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ and let $T = S + S^*$. I want to show that there is no cyclic vector for the representation of $T$ on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ i.e. $\forall x\in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ the set $P_x = \{f(x) : f\mbox{ is a polynomial in }T\}$ is not dense in $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$.

I tried to start simple, showing that if $x = \delta_n$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $P_x$ isn't dense. This worked out, but I was exploiting a symmetry that doesn't exist when considering finite linear combinations of such elements. I'm pretty sure this idea isn't going to work out.

Then I tried considering translating this operator to an operator on $L^2(S^1)$ via the Fourier transform. The corresponding operator $\hat{T}$ is simply a multiplication operator, the multiplying function being $g(t) = 2\cos(t)$. This seemed more promising initially, but I still don't see how to approach the problem outside of explicitly constructing an element $y_x$ s.t. $y_x \notin \bar{P}_x$  for arbitrary $x$.

Any hints or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Edit: Working in the $L^2(S^1)$ setting, the problem amounts to showing that $\forall f\in L^2(S^1)$ $\exists h \in L^2(S^1)$ such that $h$ cannot be approximated in $L^2$ norm by functions of the form $(\sum_{n=0}^m c_n cos^n(t))f(t).$ This seems like it should be clear, but I have been unable to prove it for general $f$.

Comment: Nevermind, I've figured it out. I figured I'd mention it in the comments instead of editing since that would bring it back to the front page.

Comment: The system has bounced the question back to the front page anyway (Jan 12 2012) so why not type up your solution here? That way the question isn't left "hanging".

Comment: Bounced again (Feb 11 2012)

Comment: To stop the cycle of bouncing, I upvoted the incorrect answer: user19255 gets +1 for effort.

Comment: That's probably not wise. We don't want to give credence to incorrect answers.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of using $H:=L^2(\mathbb T)$ is good. Let $f\in H$ and $V:=\{P(\cos\cdot)f,P\in\Bbb C[X]\}$ is dense in $H$. One can show that the closure of $V$ for the $L^2$ norm is the set $\{gf,g\mbox{ is even and in }L^2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have a partial answer.

Let $a = (a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}$ be cyclic vector for $T$

Claim: this forces $a$ to vanish either on all odd or all even integers.

Define two new vectors $b_1, b_2$ by the rule
$$
(b_k)_i = (-1)^{i+k}a_i.$$

Notice that we must have at least one $b_k \neq a$. Otherwise $a = 0$.

Sub-Claim: We have $<b_k,T^n a> = 0$ for all integers $n > 0$ and for $k=1,2$.

Proof: Just going through by hand and checking that a bunch of stuff cancels.

Now $b_k$ is orthogonal to all of $\{f(T)a: f \in \mathbb{C}[x], f(0)=0\}$ by linearity. If $Q = \{f(T)a: f \in \mathbb{C}[x]\}$ is dense in $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$, then we must be able to approximate  $b_k$ with elements of $Q$. Thus we must be able to approximate $b_k$ with scalar multiples of $a$.

It's not too hard to see that this forces $a$ to vanish either on all even or all odd integers. For if $a$ has a nonzero entry $a_{2k+1}$ and a nonzero entry $a_{2j}$, then if $(\lambda_m a)_{m=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of multiples of $a$ converging to $b_1$, then we must have $\lambda_m \to -1$ and $\lambda_m \to 1$ by division by the entry $a_{2k+1}$ or $a_{2j}$ respectively.

Thus we have shown that if $a$ is a cyclic vector, then it vanishes either on all even or all odd integers.

I think that you can keep on replicating this procedure to force all the entries of $a$ to be $0$, but I don't feel like churning out the rest of the details.

Comment: Hm... I see how you can replicate the procedure, but I don't think it forces all of the entries of $a$ to be 0. The procedure never actually ends and for an arbitrary $n$ you don't know if repeating the procedure ever actually shows that $a_n$ = 0 for that particular $n$.

Comment: Also, the sub-claim isn't true. Consider $a_0 = i, a_1 = 1, a_n = 0 $ else. Then $<Ta, b_2>$ = 2i.

Answer (score 0):

By Grasshopper's own work and Davide Giraudo's answer, it is sufficient to show that, for any $f\in L^2(S^1)$, $\left\{ gf:g\in L^\infty (S^1)\text{ is even.}\right\} \neq L^2(S^1)$.  (Of course, when we say that $g$ is even, we just mean that $g$ has an even representative.)  To show this, it suffices to exhibit a nonzero element $h\in L^2(S^1)$ that is orthogonal to every in $Ef$.  It $f=0$, then $Ef=0\neq L^(S^1)$, so we may assume that $f\neq 0$.

Let $E$ and $O$ be the subspaces of $L^2(S^1)$ consisting of the even and odd functions respectively.  It is easy to show that $L^2(S^1)\cong E\oplus O$, so for $h\in L^2(S^1)$, let us write $h=h_++h_-$ for $h_+\in E$ and $h_-\in O$.  For $h$ to be orthogonal to every $gf$, we require
$$
0=\int _{S^1}h^*(gf)=\int _{S^1}g(f_+h_+^*+f_-h_-^*).
$$
From this, we see that if we take $h_+=\sin (x)f_-^*$ and $h_-=-\sin (x)f_+^*$, then $h\neq 0$ because $f\neq 0$ and $h$ is orthogonal to every $gf$. It in turn follows that $\left\{ gf:g\in L^\infty (S^1)\text{ is even.}\right\} \neq L^2(S^1)$, competing the proof, as noted before, by Grasshopper and Davide's work.